# what exactly is returned when `return_as="generator"` is in `joblib.Parallel`?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, generator, joblib

What exactly is returned when we set `return_as="generator"` in `joblib.Parallel`?

Below, you can see that passing the generator object returned by `joblib.Parallel` into `dict()` takes less time(for most of the cases) than passing the generator object(from the sequential implementation) into `dict()`, so it's not a usual generator, I think.

```
import time
import random
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted import single_source_bellman_ford_path


def all_pairs_bellman_ford_path(G, weight="weight"):
    path = single_source_bellman_ford_path
    for n in G:
        yield (n, path(G, n, weight=weight))

def all_pairs_bellman_ford_path_parallel(G, weight="weight"):
    def _calculate_shortest_paths_subset(source):
        return (source, single_source_bellman_ford_path(G, source, weight=weight))

    nodes = G.nodes

    paths = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, return_as="generator")(
        delayed(_calculate_shortest_paths_subset)(source) for source in nodes
    )
    return paths


heatmapDF = pd.DataFrame()
number_of_nodes_list = [10, 50, 100, 300, 500]
pList = [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2]
for p in pList:
    for num in number_of_nodes_list:
        G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(num, p, seed=42, directed=False)

        random.seed(42)
        for u, v in G.edges():
            G[u][v]["weight"] = random.random()

        c = all_pairs_bellman_ford_path_parallel(G)
        t1 = time.time()
        dict(c)
        t2 = time.time()
        parallelTime = t2 - t1
        c = all_pairs_bellman_ford_path(G)
        t1 = time.time()
        dict(c)
        t2 = time.time()
        stdTime = t2 - t1
        timesFaster = stdTime / parallelTime
        heatmapDF.at[num, p] = timesFaster
        print("Finished " + str(num) + " " + str(p))

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
hm = sns.heatmap(data=heatmapDF.T, annot=True, cmap="Greens", cbar=True)
hm.set_yticklabels(pList)
hm.set_xticklabels(number_of_nodes_list)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.yticks(rotation=20)
plt.title("Times Speedups of all_pairs_bellman_ford_path")
plt.xlabel("Number of Vertices")
plt.ylabel("Edge Probability")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("timing/heatmap_all_pairs_bellman_ford_path_timing.png")
```

output:

[image: speedup heatmap]

Comment: You are solving the task in **parallel** manner and asking why it's faster than the sequential solution. Why do you think it's about generators?

Comment: To answer your exact question, it returns a result of [_get_sequential_output](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/parallel.py#L1801), which is indeed a normal generator.

Comment: Thanks @YevhenKuzmovych, But, I'm timing the `dict(c)` i.e. how much time it takes to do all the computations to evaluate the returned generators(both from parallel and sequential implementations) and not the generation time of the generators. And if the same generator objects are returned by both implementations then shouldn't they both also take the same time to evaluate and convert into a dictionary? thx :)

Comment: You misunderstand the way generators work. Generators don't have to have all the items ready when created. They can (don't have to, but can) generate items when you need them. Your sequential example indeed generates while `dict` function works on it. While the result of the parallel call can run the code (in parallel) before (or during) you call `dict`.